# Define external objects in the constructor in protected variables

Tags: magento-1.9, design-patterns

I don't think it is a pattern (if you have indicated it to me), but simply a way to improve the readability of the `local` classes, since Magento 1 does not have a management of the DI.

The approach is to define all external dependencies in protected classes in the constructor, considering that the classes could also be used only once, so this is not done with the main goal of avoiding instantiating the same class several times, the main purpose it is precisely readability.

**Do you think this approach is valid?**

```
protected $_helper;

protected $_modelProductData;

public function _construct()
{
    $this->_helper = Mage::helper('csm');

    $this->_modelProductData = Mage::getModel('csm/product_data');
}

public function getProductInfo() 
{
    // do stuff...

    return $this->_modelProductData->getInfoByProductId($productId);
}

public function getDay() 
{
    // do stuff...

    return $this->_helper->getDayFromTimestamp($timestamp);
}
```

**or is this better?**

```
public function _construct()
{
   
}

public function getProductInfo() 
{
    // do stuff...

    return Mage::helper('csm')->getInfoByProductId($productId);
}

public function getDay() 
{
    // do stuff...

    return Mage::getModel('csm/product_data')->getDayFromTimestamp($timestamp);
}
```

Comment: That's what is done in every POO language so I would say it is fine indeed. (Even considering the fact that I don't know magento 1). I can still understand what is written.

Comment: @Claims, Thanks for your answer, the recurring question is always: improve readability or write fewer lines of code? that's why I created this thread :)

Does this approach have a name, that you know of?

Comment: I would say the main rule is not to duplicate any code. So for example, if you need to use 3 times `Mage::getModel('csm/product_data')` then it's better to declare it as a model variable and then use that variable instead of calling it again 3 times.  If you use it only once like in your exemple it's debatable; but it's better to think about reusability of your code. So the better approach would be to define it as variable (eventually private if needed) in case you might need to use it later.

Comment: @Claims, Exactly about this "debatable" I was talking about, but I see that we agree, this would unify the readability and simplify the rewriting in case that method was initially used once, but then the need arose to reuse it in another method.